# How to use joblib to load a model using its azureml:// path in the Azure Machine Learning workspace

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, joblib

I registered the model ***iris_flat_model_from_cli*** in my Azure Machine Learning Workspace.

Before publishing it, for testing purposes I need to load that model from the workspace using joblib library, using the same development VM.
I can associate the model to a Python object ***m*** using

```
m = ml_client.models.get(name=m_name, version=m_version)
```

, which provides me with the path where it is registered within the Model Registry

```
azureml://subscriptions/4*****c/resourceGroups/mauromi-ml-wrkgp01/workspaces/mmAmlsWksp02/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/azureml/9c98b03d-d53d-488d-80b3-543dfc9f09f0/model_flat_output_folder/
```

, which also allows me to build the WEB path within the Storage Account

```
https://mm*****46.blob.core.windows.net/azureml-blobstore-c5*****8dc/azureml/e02c33b5-4beb-4250-9e03-9a13fbcc4a9c/model_flat_output_folder/model.pkl
```

, and I can also use the ***download*** method of the ***m*** object to download it locally and finally use it with joblib.load()

```
ml_client.models.download(name=m_name, version=m_version, download_path=m_local_base_path)
```

, which allows me to successfully run the ***predict_proba()*** inference, as shown in the below picture.

QUESTION: how can I do the same in a cleaner way without downloading it locally, e.g. passing the model path in the workspace, something like

```
model = joblib.load('azureml://subscriptions/4****c/resourceGroups/mauromi-ml-wrkgp01/workspaces/mmAmlsWksp02/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/azureml/9c98b03d-d53d-488d-80b3-543dfc9f09f0/model_flat_output_folder/model.pkl')
```

In fact, it seems that ***joblib.load()*** just accepts a local path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mlflow` to load and predict.

Follow below steps.

First import `mlflow`

```
import mlflow
m_name = "credit_defaults_model"
m_version = "1"
```

create model uri as below.

```
model_uri = "models:/"+m_name+"/"+m_version
model_uri
```

[image]

Then get model dependencies and install them using `pip`

[image]

Installation.

[image]

Without installing the dependencies, you can load module, only if you have libraries already installed.
In your case, I guess you registered and trained in same environment.

After installation, load the model and test it.

```
sk_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)
predictions = sk_model.predict(data)
predictions
```

[image]